# Disable some C# project's build events on local machine

Tags: c#, .net, csproj, build-events

There are some build events in C# project (on SVN). Is it possible to disable one of them on my local machine? I've tried to override `<PostBuildEvent>` section in `*.csproj.user`, but it does not work, all events perform anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "override?" Did you try commenting them out?

Comment: I thought that if I define same section in *.csproj.user then it will override section from *.csproj. Probably, it does not work that way

Comment: A snip from the config file, or an example resembling it, would greatly improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new build configuration, and use it in your local machine. In your build server, use another build configuration.

Comment: We currently use a lot of configurations already (not only debug|release, but different  devices and data providers). I would have to create additional copy of each frequently used of them.